# Refreshing Data For MySQL Command Line Without Exiting and Re-Entering

Tags: mysql, refresh

On Linux, I thought my MySQL queries were somehow not working, because a query would not show any progress in the amount of data being entered into a table. Is there a way the data available to the MySQL command line can be refreshed without exiting and re-entering the command line?

I have been searching around, but so far have only seen running `mysql -e` and putting that into a *bash* loop. I like to stay in the MySQL command line and run other commands like `describe tables`.

Comment: Check out the [transaction isolation levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is probably the result of a long-running `REPEATABLE-READ` transaction. Until you begin a new transaction, you can see only data that was committed at the time you started your current transaction.

Normally, the mysql client operates in `autocommit` mode. That is, every SQL statement implicitly starts and commits its own transaction. In this mode, you should always see current data every time you query. You apparently are not using autocommit mode.

You can turn on autocommit:

```
mysql> SET SESSION autocommit=1;
```

Or you can start a new transaction at your convenience:

```
mysql> BEGIN;
```

Another option is to operate within a `READ-COMMITTED` transaction. This means your transaction does not need to preserve a repeatable view of data from the time you started your transaction. It always views the most recently committed changes, even while your transaction is ongoing.

```
mysql> SET SESSION tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED';
mysql> BEGIN;
```

(Note: MySQL 8.0.3 changed the name of `tx_isolation` to `transaction_isolation`.)

The link @JimmyB posted in a comment above about [transaction isolation levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) is helpful reading.